# Split a line and then rearrange it

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a file with 130 fields separated by semicolons. I want to rearrange them in some fashion.

Consider the below example:

File *Sample.txt*:

```
1;2;3;4;8;5;6;7;9;10;11;
11;12;13;14;18;15;16;17;19;20;21;
```

Required output (file *req_op.txt*):

```
1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;
11;12;13;14;15;16;17;18;19;20;21;
```

Notice that the eighth element is misplaced. All I am doing is to streamline the line. The problem is there are 121 fields and so I am not able to use concise AWK commands to do this text manipulation in single line for the whole file.

I have tried the below and it is working. Can you suggest a more efficient or more readable solution? I request you to please also explain your solution.

Each field can have numbers and strings separated by space/string containing `$`, `#`, etc.

```
#!/bin/bash

file="sample.txt"

while read -r line
do

    array=($(echo "$line" | sed 's/;/ /g'))

    printf -v first '%s;' "${array[@]:0:4}"
    printf -v last '%s;' "${array[@]:8:12}"
    printf -v second '%s;' "${array[@]:5:3}"
    printf -v third '%s;' "${array[@]:4:1}"

    echo "${first}${second}${third}${last}" >> req_op.txt

done < $file
```

The actual number of fields:

Input:

```
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30|31|32|33|34|35|36|37|38|39|40|41|42|43|44|45|46|47|48|49|50|51|52|53|54|55|56|57|58|59|60|61|62|63|64|65|66|67|68|69|70|71|72|73|74|75|76|77|78|79|80|81|82|83|84|85|86|87|88|89|90|91|92|93|94|95|96|97|98|99|100|101|102|103|104|105|106|107|108|109|110|111|112|113|114|115|116|117|118|119|120|121|122|123|124|125|126|127|128|129|130|131|132|133|134|135|136|137|143|138|139|140|141|142|144|145|146|147|148|149|150|151|152|153|154|155|156|157|158|159|160|161|162
```

output:

```
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30|31|32|33|34|35|36|37|38|39|40|41|42|43|44|45|46|47|48|49|50|51|52|53|54|55|56|57|58|59|60|61|62|63|64|65|66|67|68|69|70|71|72|73|74|75|76|77|78|79|80|81|82|83|84|85|86|87|88|89|90|91|92|93|94|95|96|97|98|99|100|101|102|103|104|105|106|107|108|109|110|111|112|113|114|115|116|117|118|119|120|121|122|123|124|125|126|127|128|129|130|131|132|133|134|135|136|137|138|139|140|141|142|143|144|145|146|147|148|149|150|151|152|153|154|155|156|157|158|159|160|161|162
```

I modified sed command shared by @Quasímodo; and now its working as expected.

```
sed -E 's~(([^\|]*\|){137})([^\|]*\|)(([^\|]*\|){5})~\1\4\3~' sample.txt
```

Comment: Use awk. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: I wonder... is it always the 8th element, and only that, which is out of sequence, and is it always in the 5th position?  Please ignore this comment if such is always the case.  Other, consider something like `perl -F';' -lne 'print join ";", sort { $a <=> $b } @F' sample.txt`

Comment: yes only one element is out of position. Whose position is also fixed.

Comment: @SasukeUchiha I know you said awk but would you be open to a solution written in (SQL-like) query syntax? Specifically C#?

Comment: @MyWrathAcademia I need to use a bash script

Comment: @SasukeUchiha I earnestly suggest you to rollback your question to revision number 3. That was the last version of the question that was still a quesiton. Now we have two questions to deal with, after three answers have been given. That is specially complicated because, small though the change looks like, `|` is a regex metacharacter, so it would require a complete refactory in all the answers. It's totally OK to open another question if you cannot adapt the answers to your real need. And don't worry, we all were new here once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `perl`, you can also do:

```
perl -F';' -lape '$_ = join ";", @F[0..3,5..7,4,8..10]' sample
```

Or for your *actual* input:

```
perl -F'[|]' -lape '$_ = join "|", @F[0..136,138..142,137,143..161]' input
```

Comment: very neat. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

**With Awk**

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}{$8=$8 FS $5;$5=RS;sub(RS FS,"");print}' sample.txt > req_op.txt
```

Unwinded version, with comments:

```c
awk '
  BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} #Sets input (FS) and output (OFS) field separators
  {                 #For each line
    $8=$8 FS $5     #Append the 5th field after the 8th field
    $5=RS           #Put a newline (the record separator) in the 5th field
    sub(RS FS,"")   #Remove the newline and its following FS
    print           #Print the resulting line
  }     
' sample.txt > req_op.txt
```

Why was the record separator (in your case, a newline) chosen to temporarily replace the 5th field? Because it is the only character that for sure will not be in a record. Then, `sub(RS FS,"")` is certain to remove the 5th field, even if there is an empty field somewhere.

If you don't understand the `sub` line, remove it and see what happens with the output.

**With Sed**

- With extended regex:

  ```
  sed -E 's|(([^;]*;){4})([^;]*;)(([^;]*;){3})|\1\4\3|' sample.txt > req_op.txt
  ```
- With basic regex, POSIX compliant, it is basically the same as above, but every `(){}` needs to be escaped (sigh!):

  ```
  sed 's|\(\([^;]*;\)\{4\}\)\([^;]*;\)\(\([^;]*;\)\{3\}\)|\1\4\3|' sample.txt > req_op.txt
  ```

`s` is the substitution command of sed. The character that follows it is the delimiter (I chose `|`). It delimits the regex slot, the replacement slot and the flags slot (which is empty in this case).

Some elements of the regex explained:

- `[^;]*;`: Zero or more occurrences of any character except semicolon, followed by a semicolon.
- `([^;]*;){4}`: The above expression is in a capture group and it should be repeated exactly 4 times.
- `(([^;]*;){4})`: The above expression is in the outer capture group and is reproduced by `\1` in the replacement expression; The inner capture group would be replaced by `\2`.

So, what happens in the first line `1;2;3;4;8;5;6;7;9;10;11;` is

- `\1` gets `1;2;3;4;`
- `\3` gets `8;`
- `\4` gets `5;6;7;`

and they are reordered as `\1\4\3`.

For more on back-references, read [Using \1 to keep part of the pattern](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-4)
(that webpage is a nice sed tutorial by the way).

Comment: thank you for the explanation. Yes I do have empty fields. I will test it once.

Answer (score 6):

With Perl:

```
$ perl -F';' -lne 'splice @F, 7, 0, (splice @F, 4, 1); print join ";", @F' sample.txt 
1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11
11;12;13;14;15;16;17;18;19;20;21
```

See for example [Splice to slice and dice arrays in Perl](https://perlmaven.com/splice-to-slice-and-dice-arrays-in-perl)

Answer (score 0):

Python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
k=open('filename','r')
r=[]
v=[]
for i in k:
    r=[]
    v=[]
    j=i.strip().split(";")
    for g in j:
        if (g != ''):
            r.append(int(g.strip()))
    r.sort()
    e=r
    for d in e:
        v.append(str(d))
        v.append(str(";"))
    print "".join(v)
```

output

```
1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;
11;12;13;14;15;16;17;18;19;20;21;
```